# VB seems to lose newlines when called over COM

Tags: vb.net, com

I have a VB method

```
Public Sub append_text(ByVal s As String)
    f1.TextBox1.AppendText(s)
End Sub
```

which is called over COM from C++

```
_bstr_t b(L"test\nnew\nlines\n");
ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(t->append_text(b));
```

But the text box ends up saying

```
testnewlines
```

Without the aforementioned new lines.

Why is that then?

Comment: Please pay more attention to your tag choices. This would have been the only question on Stack Overflow tagged 'vb' out of over 2 million.  Instead, use a more specific tag: vbscript, vba, vb6, vb.net.

Comment: I'm not a VB programmer so this is merely a guess, but adding a `\r` in front of the `\n` might make a difference. Windows usually considers the `\r\n` couple as a new line.

Comment: This fixes it.  Wow.  I had no idea!

Comment: Isn't newline in windows `\r\f`? Wouldn't `\r\n` be the equivalent of `\r\r\f`? My understanding is that `\n` is usually the system dependent newline, thus on windows the `\r\f` pair.

Comment: `\f` is form feed (ASCII 12); `\n` is line feed (ASCII 10); `\r` is carriage return (ASCII 13); `\r\n` is a Windows newline; `\n` is a Unix newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>For the sake of completeness, posting my comment as an answer (now that I know it's correct...):</sub>

Different operating systems consider different character combinations as new lines. The *nixes, for instance, use a single `\n`, as in your code. Windows, on the other hand, uses the `\r\n` combination. Therefore, the single `\n` in your string just isn't enough to be considered a new line marker. Using `\r\n` will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks.  I've been trying to fix this from the VB side, without success.  The following crashes:  For i = 0 To s.Length
            f1.TextBox1.AppendText(Asc(s.Substring(i)) + vbNewLine)
        Next

Comment: (The above loop was just to figure out what unicode representation of \n I was getting so I could substitute it)

Answer (score 1):

Eran is right.

To fix it on the VB side, try this

```
 Dim s2 As String = s.Replace(vbLf, vbCrLf) 
 f1.TextBox1.AppendText(s2)
```

**EDIT** Sideshow Bob has compiled and tested this.